# Capture image output file android 10

Tags: android, android-camera, scoped-storage

I am migrating to scoped storage and I have removed `requestlegacyexternalstorage` from manifest file.

After that, when capturing image with camera, the image not saved to provided path `tempImageCameraPath`.

```
override fun permissionAccepted() {
                    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
                    if (GuiUtils.intentCanResolve(intent)) {
                        tempImageCameraPath = String.format(FileUtils.getImageDir().toString() + "/%s" + Constants.PNG_IMAGE_FORMAT,
                                FileUtils.getNewFileName())
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, FileUtils.getUriForWrite(tempImageCameraPath, intent))
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_IMG_FROM_CAMERA)
                    }
                }
```

Image dir is `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

Write permissions `FileUtils.getUriForWrite`

```
public static Uri getUriForWrite(String filePath, Intent intent) {
        Uri uri = getUriForFile(filePath);
        App.get().grantUriPermission(CommonUtils.getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        resolveUriForIntent(uri, intent, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        return uri;
    }

public static Uri getUriForFile(String filePath) {
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(App.get(), CommonUtils.getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", new File(filePath));
    }
```

Cannot find any errors related to camera in logs, it just not saves the file.
I tried to change to internal directories, but it not work too.

Comment: `getUriForFile(filePath)` we have no idea what that function does or what it returns.

Comment: @blackapps updated

Comment: Put flags on the intent for read/write permission.

Comment: Intent already has write permission

Comment: No, that will not work i think. Put the flag with intent,setFlags() on the intent you use for startActivityForResult. Im afraid that all that grantUriPermission stuff does nothing.

Comment: But why, what is the difference? with `requestlegacyexternalstorage=true` every thing worked fine, how does not legacy storage impact on this

Comment: `But why, what is the difference?` Well... did you try? Please first try and report before you have other questions.

Comment: `After that, when capturing image with camera, the image not saved to provided path ` Of course not. You try to save an image to a public directory on external storage : `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`. And on an Android 10 device that directory is not usable withou requesting legacy external storage. Sorry i just saw what you do now. What makes you think you would have access without it?

Comment: `I tried to change to internal directories, but it not work too.` Dont know what you mean by that but you can use getExternalFilesDir() and getFilesDir() without any permission. Only then you can really say: `I am migrating to scoped storage`.